# Fast algorithm needed

Tags: algorithm

Given two numbers start and stop and the following loop with a fixed number of iterations n.

```
res = start
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    res = res * c;
```

At the end of the loop res shall equal stop +/- some error.

How do I compute c. A code example would be appreciated.

Edit:

The accepted answer gives the probably fastest way using the pow function. But what if start and stop are indeed integers and the computed c may be approximated.

My humble effort for the 'fastest' algorithm is:

```
float (int start, int stop, int n) {

      float delta = some number; // which would be the best entry point for delta?

      float c = some number; // which the best for c?

      int error = 1; // integer too. But does this matter?

      while(delta > error) {

          res = start;

          for(i=0; i<n, res<stop;i++)
              res = res * c;

          delta = distance(res, stop);

          if(res > stop)
              c += some number; //which number here?
          else
              c -= some number; //and here?
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Are the involved numbers integers or reals?

Comment: Questions about algorithms better fit on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). See [Where should I post questions about algorithms: Stack Overflow or Software Engineering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-software-engin) for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make simple algebraic transformations

```
start * c^n = stop
c^n = stop / start
c = (stop / start)^(1/n)
```

(`math.pow` or `power` function in some programming languages)